# can't connect to mongo docker within gitlab

Tags: mongodb, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have the following docker image built by the next docker-compose

```
services:
    give_sync_test:
        image: mongo:4.2.10
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mybase
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: password
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
```

which i am using through the following gitlab step :

```
test:
    stage: test
    dependencies:
        - maven_build_snapshot
    image: 'my_image:latest'
    before_script:
        - apt-get update
        - apt-get -y install git
        - mongo "mongodb://localhost:27017/mybase" < ./utils/test
```

the content of utils/test is simply :

```
use myBase;
```

no action in this, the real problem is that i'm getting the following error from gitlab-ci :

> connecting to:
> mongodb://localhost:27017/give?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> 2020-12-09T14:44:21.828+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect
> to server localhost:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
> Error connecting to localhost:27017 (127.0.0.1:27017) :: caused by ::
> Connection refused : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:353:17
> @(connect):2:6 2020-12-09T14:44:21.830+0000 F  -        [main]
> exception: connect failed 2020-12-09T14:44:21.830+0000 E  -
> [main] exiting with code 1

I've already try the mongo string with some authentication as well
mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017/mybase

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `alias` of the `services` to connect to the containers. In this case, you can access mongo by using this connection string `mongodb://admin:password@give_sync_test:27017/mybase`